# Determine aggregation rate from particle size growth rate

Tags: physical-chemistry, calculus

How to compute aggregation rate of particles is particle growth rate is known?
As far as I understand $\frac{dN}{dt}$ is aggregation rate i.g. change of number of particle per time unit. $\frac {d R_h}{d t}$ is change of particle hydrodynamic radius per time unit. I understand that when particle size increases by two number of particles decreases by two.

Comment: The answer to this problem may require that you post a picture of the system being considered. In particular, what are the bounds on the distribution of particles sizes and their separation at the initial state.

Comment: That is the main problem. I don't know how to precisely formulate this question. As far as I know that question should be formulated in such a way that it would correctly describe aggregation of real particles.